# Convert from ndarray of lists into ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Convertion from 2d ndarray of lists into 3d ndarray, I have .npy file created by code similar to ths below. How to convert from (2,2) into (2,2,3) ndarray ?
`results` object already exists and below code can't be changed, conversion from 
(2,2) `results` `ndarray` into (2,2,3) is what I need

```
dtypes = [('value_model', np.float64),
         ('value_simulator', np.float64), 
         ('vector_optimum', object)]

results = np.zeros((2,2), dtype = dtypes) 

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        results['vector_optimum'][i, j] = list(range(1+i+2*j,4+i+2*j))

print(results['vector_optimum'])
"""
[[list([1, 2, 3]) list([3, 4, 5])]
 [list([2, 3, 4]) list([4, 5, 6])]]
"""
results['vector_optimum'].shape
#Out[4]: (2, 2)
```

How to convert results['vector_optimum'] from (2,2) to (2,2,3) ndarray ?

Comment: A (2,2,3) array has 3x as many values as a (2,2) one.  What are the new values supposed to be?  0s?  Replicas of the original?  some thing else?  It's not just a matter of 'conversion' or 'reshape'; it's about making 'new' data.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to keep the `results` object as you have constructed it, the easiest thing is probably to create a `(2, 2, 3)` matrix called, say, `new_results` and populate that in a loop. Then if you want, you can re-assign `results` to this `new_results` value. Like this:

```
dtypes = [('value_model', np.float64),
         ('value_simulator', np.float64),
         ('vector_optimum', object)]

results = np.zeros((2,2), dtype = dtypes)

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        results['vector_optimum'][i, j] = list(range(1+i+2*j,4+i+2*j))

print(results['vector_optimum'])
"""
[[list([1, 2, 3]) list([3, 4, 5])]
 [list([2, 3, 4]) list([4, 5, 6])]]
"""
results['vector_optimum'].shape
#Out[4]: (2, 2)

# JUST ADD THIS BIT

new_results = np.zeros((2, 2, 3), dtype=dtypes)

for i in range(new_results.shape[0]):
    for j in range(new_results.shape[1]):
        for k in range(new_results.shape[2]):
            new_results["vector_optimum"][i][j][k] = results[i][j][-1][k]

results = new_results


print(results["vector_optimum"][0][0][0])  # prints "1"
```

Comment: yes you are right, but `results` already exists I load it from .npy file and have to convert it into something useful

Comment: OK I edited my answer. Hopefully it fits your needs.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept the answer :)

Comment: now, because you have modified code I have posted, final  `results` object is what you have to operate on

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the solution to be something that runs _after_ everything you have posted?

Comment: yes, there should be possibility to write: `results['vector_optimum'][0,0,0]`

Comment: I have edited one more time. This time I am certain it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following piece of code

```
results = results.reshape((results.shape[0], results.shape[1], 1))
results.shape
```

Output:

```
(2, 2, 1)
```

Comment: third dimension should be 3 not 1

Comment: This answer is on the right track but `resize` is better for the OP use case.
`reshape` can only "shuffle" the shape, so it could turn (2,2) into (2, 1, 1), for example.